# How to prevent GROUP_CONCAT from creating a result when no input data is present?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Given the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  `show`.`id`
  , GROUP_CONCAT( `showClips`.`clipId` ORDER BY `position` ASC ) AS 'playlist'
FROM
  `show`
  INNER JOIN
    `showClips`
      ON
        ( `show`.`id` = `showClips`.`showId` )
;
```

I want to retrieve a list of all "shows" from the database, including the ids of contained "clips".

This works fine, as long as there are entries in the `show` table. For this problem, let's assume all tables are completely empty.

`GROUP_CONCAT` will return `NULL` and thus forcing a row into the result (which contains only `NULL` values).

My application will then think that one show/result exists. But that result will be invalid. This can of course be checked, but I feel like this could (and should) be prevented in the query already.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should simply add a `GROUP BY` at the end.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE `show` (id int);
CREATE TABLE `showClips` (clipId int, showId int, position int);

SELECT 
   `show`.`id`,
   GROUP_CONCAT( `showClips`.`clipId` ORDER BY `position` ASC ) AS 'playlist'
FROM  `show`
INNER JOIN `showClips` ON ( `show`.`id` = `showClips`.`showId` )
GROUP BY `show`.`id`;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: it's worth mentioning that you can do `GROUP BY NULL` if you want to avoid creating a result from an empty set but want don't want results grouped by any particular column

Answer (score 12):

Add group by `show`.`id`, then result will be correct for empty tables:

create table emptyt(id int, name varchar(20));

```
   select id, group_concat(name) from emptyt
```

result:

```
 NULL, NULL
```

query with group by

```
 select id, group_concat(name) from emptyt
 group by Id
```

result:

empty dataset

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark Daniel's response as the answer, as he seemed to have been a second quicker.